# I want to add a Decimal number as hours to a date in php

Tags: php, time

How can I add 0.25 hours to a date?

For example:

```
$time = 0.25;
$mid = date_create("00:00") ;
```

and now I want to add `$time` as hours to `$mid`.

With `$time = 0.25` I mean 1/4 of a hour. But I only get variables from 0.01 - 0.99;

Comment: Not clear from your question. can you please write your desire output.

Comment: Simply calculate the value. *60 mins = 1 hours* rest you can calculate I guess.

Comment: What do you mean with "0.25 hours"? 25 minutes or 1/4 hour (15 minutes)?

Comment: i did a edit.. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `date_add` to add `$time * 3600` seconds to your `$mid` date.

```
$time = 0.25;
$mid = date_create("00:00") ;
date_add($mid, date_interval_create_from_date_string(($time*3600).' seconds'));
echo date_format($mid, 'H:i:s');
```